# Posibility to change string of code in a middle of a method with super() in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to subclass following serializer:

```
User = get_user_model()



class UidAndTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    uid = serializers.CharField()
    token = serializers.CharField()

    default_error_messages = {
        "invalid_token": settings.CONSTANTS.messages.INVALID_TOKEN_ERROR,
        "invalid_uid": settings.CONSTANTS.messages.INVALID_UID_ERROR,
    }

    def validate(self, attrs):
        validated_data = super().validate(attrs)

        # uid validation have to be here, because validate_<field_name>
        # doesn't work with modelserializer
        try:
            uid = utils.decode_uid(self.initial_data.get("uid", ""))
            self.user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except (User.DoesNotExist, ValueError, TypeError, OverflowError):
            key_error = "invalid_uid"
            raise ValidationError(
                {"uid": [self.error_messages[key_error]]}, code=key_error
            )

        is_token_valid = self.context["view"].token_generator.check_token(
            self.user, self.initial_data.get("token", "")
        )
        if is_token_valid:
            return validated_data
        else:
            key_error = "invalid_token"
            raise ValidationError(
                {"token": [self.error_messages[key_error]]}, code=key_error
            )
```

in order to use it’s validate() method. It fully satisfies me except one thing:
I want to change

```
self.user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
```

to

```
self.user = User._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
```

Is it any way to do it somehow with `super()` and not copy-paste whole thing from superclass to sublclass?
Thank you.
What I did now , its kind of sketchy...

```
class CommitUndeleteUserAccountSerializer(UidAndTokenSerializer):

    def validate(self, attrs):
        User = get_user_model()
        User.objects = User._default_manager
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if not self.user.deleted:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                *error_codes.NOT_SOFT_DELETED
            )
        return attrs
```

It works but it might be dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define special method to get user instance:

```
class UidAndTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    uid = serializers.CharField()
    token = serializers.CharField()

    default_error_messages = {
        "invalid_token": settings.CONSTANTS.messages.INVALID_TOKEN_ERROR,
        "invalid_uid": settings.CONSTANTS.messages.INVALID_UID_ERROR,
    }

    def _get_user(self, uid):
        return get_user_model().objects.get(pk=uid)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        validated_data = super().validate(attrs)

        # uid validation have to be here, because validate_<field_name>
        # doesn't work with modelserializer
        try:
            uid = utils.decode_uid(self.initial_data.get("uid", ""))
            self.user = self._get_user(uid=uid)
        except (User.DoesNotExist, ValueError, TypeError, OverflowError):
            key_error = "invalid_uid"
            raise ValidationError(
                {"uid": [self.error_messages[key_error]]}, code=key_error
            )

        is_token_valid = self.context["view"].token_generator.check_token(
            self.user, self.initial_data.get("token", "")
        )
        if is_token_valid:
            return validated_data
        else:
            key_error = "invalid_token"
            raise ValidationError(
                {"token": [self.error_messages[key_error]]}, code=key_error
            )
```

and in second class override only that method:

```
class CommitUndeleteUserAccountSerializer(UidAndTokenSerializer):
    def _get_user(self, uid):
        return get_user_model()._default_manager.get(pk=uid)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if not self.user.deleted:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                *error_codes.NOT_SOFT_DELETED
            )
        return attrs
```

without all this dangerous dancing with manager

Comment: Problem is that superclass is in source code of 3rd part package. I cant modify it

Comment: @AlekseiKhatkevich  then create your own base serializer class and override validate method and add _get_user method